# C++11 regex is not multi-thread safe library?

Tags: c++11

I have tried some experiments on c++11 regex using multithread and I think it's not multi thread safe library.

I just can't explain more. Please help me :(

Comment: And what is your specific problem?

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation. I use while(std::regex(s,m,e){} code and I get deadlock.

Comment: @Young: That doesn't make sense -- your expression in the `while` returns a `std::regex`, not `bool`. That shouldn't compile. Please post the actual code with which you're having problems and perhaps we can better help.

Comment: Please add a Short, Self Contained, Correct/Compilable, Example: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `const` member functions of a `regex` is a thread safe operation. Calling non-`const` member functions is not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Considering the only way to make things like that thread safe would be to enter a lock, if you want that to be thread safe, then just protect the `regex` with a lock.